# change action bar icon as a response of dialogfragment

Tags: android, menu, android-dialogfragment

In my activiy, I open a DialogFragment to insert data in db.
When I'm done, i dismiss the dialog, but I would like to change the sync icon of the activity to a red sync icon ( to say the user there is data to sync).
The only way I can do is just before I dismiss, call a public method that belongs to the activity from the dialog, but I can't reach the Menu Items
How can I do???

Comment: Why can't you reach the Menu Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I close the dialog, I call a method that invoke from the DialogFragment:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

then, it enters in the onPrepare Method :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuSync= menu.findItem(R.id.menu_sync);
    int sincronizado = prefs.getInt("sincronizado", 0);
   if (sincronizado == 1)
       menuSync.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_update_red);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```